# How to grant elevation with Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2, elevated-privileges

I have written a database app that imports data from an excel file into a Access database.

I have never had trouble to run the app, to insert records into the database, but as soon as I run the function to import data from the Excel into the Access I get the following warning:

The requested operation requires elevation - by die code:

```
LAccess := CreateOleObject('Access.Application');
```

What is causing this and is there a way to get around it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`CreateOleObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.ComObj.CreateOleObject) delphi function internally calls the [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi method which requires elevation. you have a couple of options to deal with this.

1) Adding a manifest to your app including the [requested execution level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) *requireAdministrator*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    name="Your app name goes here"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    version="5.1.0.0"
    type="win32"/>
<description>your app description goes here</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
           type="win32"
           name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
           version="6.0.0.0"
           processorArchitecture="x86"
           publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
           language="*"
        />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
   </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

2) You can launch a secondary process elevated that would do the task or create a COM object that runs elevated, you can find more info in these MSDN entries

- [`Redesign for UAC Compatibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx)
- [The COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: processorArchitecture="*" is supported to indicate that all processor architectures.